# Is it really possible to cause military-grade explosives to explode with a gun shot?

Tags: realism, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

At the end of *Suicide Squad*:

> Harley Quinn cuts out Enchantress' heart. Rick Flag asks Killer Croc to throw a military-grade explosive into Enchantress' weapon and Deadshot shoots it, forcing it to explode.

According to [IMDB Goof's](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1386697/trivia?tab=gf&ref_=tt_trv_gf#plot_hole), it states,

> Military-grade explosives do not explode when shot at; the (sic) require a blasting cap to be set off. This is a safety feature of such materials.

However, it is observed that shooting a grenade or fuel tank causes it to explode. Is this not possible with the explosive used in this scenario?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the video/picture of the gun? High calibers are able to handle [*trick* bullets](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TrickBullet), paired with his precision (also in switching bullets at the right pace) he might well be shooting [holy electric sizzling radioactive silver bullets](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DepletedPhlebotinumShells).

Comment: You added a spoiler tag for a scientific fact, but not when describing the end of the movie?

Comment: @user3819867 https://youtu.be/Hdr0Q3mQ4fs

Comment: There is an excellent Mythbusters Episode (#175) where they do all sorts of fun stuff to C4, including setting it on fire, shooting it with various types of ammo (incendiary, tracer), dumping thermite on it, stomping on it...

Comment: Define "Military-grade explosives". If you're talking about [Tannerite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannerite), then yes. The verbiage you're after is *impact [sensitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_(explosives))*. *Primary explosives* do, *secondary explosives* do not.

Comment: "Military grade" is not that useful of a classification: [*primary* and *secondary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosive_material#By_sensitivity) does describe how explosives behave.

Comment: "it is observed that shooting a grenade or fuel tank causes it to explode". No, that is wrong too. Mythbusters did an episode of that where they shot at grenades and found that they did not explode when shot at, even if you manage to break them apart violently. The only thing that happens is that the explosive is dispersed. Fuel tanks... same thing. You need to aerosolise, or boil, or in any other manner vapourise fuel in order to make it explode.

Comment: Also worth to note: Explosive Ordnance Disposal teams uses **explosives** to safely dispose of **bombs**. Unless it is a very old and/or degraded piece of ordnance, elongated shaped charges are applied along the the casing. When the charge is set off, it will cut open the casing, and then disperse the explosive without detonating it. That is how safe modern explosives are.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors .. came to say the same thing .. Mythbusters actually did an episode where they cooked with C4 .. turned out to be a great alternative fuel to heat up the MRE's in less than 5 minutes :)

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors I thought using explosives to dispose of bombs was just a sure-fire way to render them safe by reliably detonating them (HE explosions are a good way to detonate even the least-sensitive explosives). Some things like the BootBanger I guess try to scatter them, but I think those are specialty cases.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that shooting things to make them blow up is a pervasive trope in television and films, similar to any character being able to knock out any other character with a single blow when it's convenient to the plot, or shooting locks, both traditional and electronic, to open doors, regardless of the caliber of the firearm and without any risk of ricochet or shrapnel.

Comment: @NickT That is probably the case in many instances too.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### NO

Military Grade explosives are incredibly safe and are **designed** to only explode when required.

Take C4 (or Composition-4 to give it its correct name) - [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-4_(explosive))

> C-4 is very stable and insensitive to most physical shocks. **C-4 cannot be detonated by a gunshot or by dropping it onto a hard surface.** It does not explode when set on fire or exposed to microwave radiation. Detonation can only be initiated by a combination of extreme heat and a shockwave, such as when a detonator inserted into it is fired.

---

### Shooting Gas Tanks

This was covered at [Skeptics Stack Exchange](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2343/can-you-make-an-explosion-by-shooting-at-fuel-or-fuel-tank) where the answer was a pretty resounding... **NO**.

Comment: There's a great urban legend around the safety of C4 in the military.  It goes like this: One day an EOD instructor is giving a presentation on C4.  He says that, contrary to what you see in movies, it is very stable. You can squeeze it, stomp on it, hell, you could even chew on it, and it won't explode.  He passes a small bit around the class to examine and continues on with his presentation.  He's interrupted by a soldier in the back of the class that vomits, collapses, and begins to have seizures.  Turns out the guy decided to test out the chewing part and didn't know that C4 is poisonous.

Comment: @Kevin I'm sure I read somewhere that soldiers will occasionally eat very small bits of C4 to avoid unpleasant duties

Comment: A gas tank CAN, erm, flare if given the right conditions:  fuel/air mixture, ignition source via maybe an incendiary round. But the tank would have to be larger than a automotive tank, and as automotive tanks are specifically designed not to explode..............I do really wish the motion picture industry would get a little bit real on that point.

Comment: Also Fuel tank != gas tank. Liquid petroleum gas is highly difficult to ignite. Propane tanks are another story.

Comment: I may have been hasty in my first comment. I believe they threw a hand grenade which is nothing like c4...

Comment: @cde Even propane tanks are hard to ignite.  FPS Russia did it a while back.  He had to put flares on the tanks to ignite the escaping gas, or use incendiary rounds.

Comment: This is a great answer but it makes some assumptions. If it's already primed with an impact sensitive detonator it is a whole other story.

Comment: *The general answer is correct I feel.* The explosives don't detonate because they were shot. They explode because the **detonator** was detonated by the effects of the shot.  As has been said, without the detonator...nothing happens.

Comment: Lies!  Auto fuel tanks are death bombs waiting to explode.  Or are you telling me that CHiPs was not a science-based documentary?

Comment: Mythbusters even cooked with C4! They set it on fire and heated water with it.

Answer (score 11):

'Military Grade' does not really define what the explosive is made of, and that is what determines how it detonates.  Some explosives require fire, some impact, some a chemical reaction, etc.   Many nitrogen based explosives can explode with physical force.  I've seen nitrogen triiodide explode at the touch of a feather.  TNT is also know to explode if not handled properly.  Bullets themselves have a primer that is impact based which ignites the gunpowder.

If a bomb has an impact based detonator, or uses an impact based explosive, then yes, shooting it would detonate it.  'Military Grade' doesn't specify what it is.

Comment: +1. But I will add that a military grade bomb or munition will have a military grade fuze (also spelled fuse). These fuzes are intelligent enough to have safety features like achieving a set spin rate before arming itself (there are other features as well). The charge on this type of munition is pretty stable, and will only go high order (detonate) when its fuze fires off.

Comment: "how else?" - they use altimeters

Answer (score 7):

### Yes

But only certain ones. In Mythbusters Episode 216, they detonate a hand grenade with a .308 rifle.

http://mythresults.com/fire-in-the-hole

Comment: The rifle shot *probably* detonated the blasting cap which then detonated the grenade...but a good answer.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Possibly, but the grenade detonated as soon as the round hit the outside of the grenade, and before it reached the cap. Perhaps the shock proceeded it to the cap, but that's hard to say.

Comment: OTOH, let's just call a blasting cap, "military-grade explosives." :)

Comment: @DonBranson  But blasting caps are also industrial.  So....yeah.

Comment: @NZKshatriya - Okay, so C4 and blasting caps also have commercial/industrial use. Not sure what you're saying.

Comment: Just pointing out that classifying blasting caps as military grade explosives is a no-go.

Comment: @NZKshatriya - Obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Explosives that detonate with combustion or shock can be set off with firearms......Thought difficult. Sensitive explosives like TNT are indeed possible. 
Modern military explosives use RDX or plastic explosives that are notoriously difficult to set off. This makes them safer. They can only detonate with a high speed detonation wave (primer caps)